# What is the hash equivalent of contain_exactly for RSpec?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, ruby-hash

I need to verify the contents of a hash, and I was surprised to find that RSpec's `contain_exactly` only works on arrays. The ideal expectation is:

```rb
expect(type.values.values).to contain_exactly(
  ONE: an_object_having_attributes(value: 'uno'),
  TWO: an_object_having_attributes(value: 'dos')
)
```

The base requirement is that `contain_exactly` requires that the array have *only* those elements, and a hash equivalent must only contain the exact key/value pairs specified.

There's plenty of workarounds that are just *okay*:

- `include(key: value)`, but this allows other keys, I need an exact match.
- `expect(hash.keys).to contain_exactly(...)` but that doesn't verify that the keys are specifically linked to the values.
- use `contain_exactly` anyway (which reads the hash as a tuple of `[key, value]`) and match based on the sub-array e.g. `contain_exactly(a_collection_containing_exactly('ONE', an_object_having_attributes(value: 'uno')), ...)`
- iterate through the hash and match keys to values based on an expected input with `aggregate_failures`.

etc. but I'm mostly curious if there's a built-in RSpec way to do this.

Comment: `expect to eq`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks, but it can't use `eq` because the spec needs to check that the object in the `value` has a specific attribute without generating the entire object (which in my current case case is not possible.)

Comment: yeah, i thought it'd work, but I checked just now and it doesn't.

Comment: Use a newer Ruby with pattern matching, and verify that you can match the pattern.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs not only in new versions. I try in 2.4 and `match` works

Comment: @mechnicov I'm referring to [pattern matching](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.1/doc/syntax/pattern_matching_rdoc.html), which is a newish feature Ruby introduced in (I think) 2.7.4 and evolving in 3.1.

Comment: It was introduced in 2.7.0 as experimental feature

Answer (score 8):

You can use `match` matcher like this

```rb
require "ostruct"

describe do
  let(:hash) do
    {
      one: OpenStruct.new(x: 1),
      two: OpenStruct.new(y: 2)
    }
  end

  it "matches hashes" do
    expect(hash).to match(
      two: an_object_having_attributes(y: 2),
      one: an_object_having_attributes(x: 1)
    )
  end

  it "requires the actual to have all elements of the expected" do
    expect(a: 1, b: 2).not_to match(b: 2)
  end

  it "requires the expected to have all elements of the actual" do
    expect(a: 1).not_to match(a: 1, b: 2)
  end
end
```

If one of this hashes has extra key(s) -- test will fail

Comment: This does not satisfy the requirement that it must match exactly the inputs. This will still succeed if `hash` has other keys. This is implied by the use case of `contain_exactly`, but I added an extra line to clarify.

Comment: What inputs? This code check if hash contains only given keys as you write in your question, also check values like in your question

Comment: I believe this answer is correct. I added some more examples to the answer and they all pass for me with RSpec 3.12.0.

Comment: Thank you for new example @JordanBrough. Yes, it works in older versions too, I use it in my projects