# Matching of randomly ordered array when test nested hash with RSpec

Tags: arrays, ruby, rspec, ruby-hash

In my RSpec tests I often have the challenge to compare deep nested hashes like this

```rb
{ foo: ["test", { bar: [1,2,3] }] }
```

The values `[1,2,3]` are read from a DB where the order is not guaranteed, nor do I care about the order. So when I compare the two hashes in my test, I always have to make sure on both sides that the order is enforced:

```rb
# my_class.rb
class MyClass
  def self.data
    read_db.sort
  end
end

expected_data = { foo: ["test", { bar: [1,2,3].sort }] }
expect(MyClass.data).to eq(expected_data)
```

I really dislike the fact, that I have to alter my production code only because of my test env.

I could of course stop comparing the whole hash and focus on the single keys, and therefore could remove the custom sorting inside my production code:

```rb
actual_data = MyClass.data
expect(actual_data.fetch(:foo)[0]).to eq("test")
expect(actual_data.fetch(:foo)[1].fetch(:bar)).to match_array([1,2,3])
```

But this makes the whole spec pretty complicated and hard to read.

So I thought about **creating a custom "unordered array" class `Bag`** that, when it get's compared, ignores the order:

```rb
class Bag < Array
  def eql?(other)
    sort_by(&:hash) == other.sort_by(&:hash)
  end
  alias == eql?
end
```

But this works only, when the `Bag` class is on the left side of the comparison:

```
expect(Bag.new([1, "2"])).to eq(["2", 1])

 1 example, 0 failures
```

But that's usually not the case, as the expected value in a test should be inside `expect(...)`, which represents the values from the DB:

```
expect(["2", 1]).to eq(Bag.new([1, "2"]))

 Failure/Error: expect(["2", 1]).to eq(Bag.new([1, "2"]))
   expected: [1, "2"]
        got: ["2", 1]
   (compared using ==)

 1 example, 1 failure
```

The reason behind this is, that `Array#==` is called and not my custom `Bag#==` method.

I looked into the docs ([https://devdocs.io/ruby~3.2/array#method-i-3D-3D](https://devdocs.io/ruby%7E3.2/array#method-i-3D-3D)) where it states

> Returns true if both array.size == other_array.size and for each index i in array, array[i] == other_array[i]:

But here I came to a stop, as **I wasn't able to figure out, how to implement the fetching of a value for a specific index. I tried implementing `Bar#[]` and `Bar#fetch` but they aren't called when comparing objects.**

Maybe it's not possible at all because array calls some low level C function that can't be overriden. But maybe someone knows a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could of course stop comparing the whole hash

You can continue to compare whole hash. RSpec is very powerful tool

RSpec allows you to use its matchers DSL directly in the expected code

Therefore why don't use this feature?

Additionally, there is a feature, which detailed documentation I did not find:

[This is using `match` for hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71444640/10608621)

```
RSpec.describe do
  let(:hsh) { { foo: ["test", { bar: [1,2,3] }] } }

  it 'check nested hashes well' do
    expect(hsh).to match(foo: contain_exactly("test", match(bar: contain_exactly(1, 2, 3))))
  end
end
```

Here `match` and `contain_exactly` are used in the expected output. Of course you can use `match_array` like `match_array([1, 2, 3])` or any other matchers

Answer (score 3):

I would use `match` with a nested `match_array` like this:

```
it 'matches when nested arrays having different sorting' do
  data = { foo: ['test', { bar: [3, 2, 1] }] }

  expect(data).to match(
    { foo: ['test', bar: match_array([1, 2, 3])] }
  )
end
```